# How to implement listeners for selectionModel within controller in ExtJS 4.1 MVC

Tags: extjs

I have a grid with `checkboxmodel` selection model applied. Is there a way to put listeners on it within controllers `control()` method?

As far as [DOCS](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.app.Controller) say `refs` property is used to reference to Components only. SelectionModel is not a Component.

Comment: what do you want to do with `selectionmodel`?

Comment: I want to process `select` events on checkboxes.

Comment: @webbandit the grid will fire these event for you. You don'T need to dig up to the checkboxmodel

Comment: then do it on grid's selection, you can add cellclick event to controller

Comment: Grigs `select` event is fired `after a record is selected`. I do need fire event if checkbox from `checkboxmodel` was selected only.

Comment: @webbandit As you might see in the [API](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.selection.CheckboxModel-event-selectionchange) the checkboxes checkboxmodel are not of the type Ext.form.field.Checkbox. For that reason there is not single event from the checkbox that you may have in mind. To force selection by using the checbox see may answer (edit comes shortly)

Comment: But I've already implemented my task by putting listeners directly in `checkboxmodel` configuration object and catching `select` event. There is single event from every checkbox in `checkboxmodel`.

Comment: @webbandit As already mentioned the checkboxmodel has a select event but this is totally the same that get fired by the grid itself. So there is no need to register it there cause it get bubbled up to the grid. (fixed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply register your listeners to the grid that contains this model using the supplied control() method of your controller. As far as I know all events from the checkboxmodel are bubbled up to grid. At least the selectionchange event works cause I use this one by myself along with a checkbox model.

```
'grid': {select: this.onSelect, selectionchange: this.onSelectionChange}
```

I don't recommend to use refs at all for such a case.

Edit:

As you might see in the [API](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.selection.CheckboxModel-event-selectionchange) the checkboxes checkboxmodel are not of the type Ext.form.field.Checkbox. For that reason there is not single event from the checkbox that you may have in mind.

To force a selection by using the checkbox use

```
checkOnly: true
```

this will force a selection only by clicking the combo

Comment: You mean write everything in `listeners` property of `checkboxmodel`?

Comment: @webbandit No. Register at as a control within the controller like `'grid': {selectionchange: this.onSelectionChange}`

Comment: Thanks for the idea for @sra! As you said `checkboxmodel` events are bubbled up to its grid. I use `beforeselect` event on grid and get as a parameters needed `checkboxmodel` and also a `record` selected.